# How to get first and last record from same group in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a new SQL user and need help.

Let's say I have a vehicle number 123 and I've traveled from Region 3 to final destination Region 4. In between, I've visited Region 1 and 5 as well but that's not my concern.
Simple example would be as follow.

Original Table

[image: Original Table]

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

How can this be done in SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sequence number so you can use some form of aggregation.  One method is:

```
select records,
       max(case when sequence = 1 then fromregion end) as fromregion,
       max(case when sequence = maxsequence then toregion) as toregion
from (select t.*, max(sequence) over (partition by records) as max_sequence
      from t
     ) t
group by records;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't offer "first()" or "last()" as aggregation functions.  But it does support `first_value()` as a *window* function.  This allows you to do the logic without a subquery:

```
select distinct records,
       first_value(fromRegion) over (partition by records order by sequence) as fromregion,
       first_value(toRegion) over (partition by records order by sequence desc) as toregion
from t;
```